# Django different clients with users

Tags: django, django-models

For a SaaS Application, I would like to have a custom subsite for each Client. Each subsite will have Users, for which I would like to use Django's default User Model.

The subsite is defined by the subdomain, so e.g. `client1.example.com` and `client2.example.com` will be two different subsites that run on the same application.

I would like to have unique Users in each subsite, so e.g. `alice@email.com` would be able to sign up for multiple subsites with the same username (email).

How can I alter the Django User Model to also include a `client_id` and then perform a `unique_together` constraint on both `client_id` and `username`? Do I have to rewrite the whole authentication backend for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Currently trying to do it myself and using Tenant schema, but it won't let me create a shared user.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll be sufficient to define your own user model.

Derive from `AbstractBaseUser`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

and you will need `unique_together = ('client_id', 'username',)`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#unique-together

edit:

found solution in SO

[Django 1.7 multisite User model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898726/django-1-7-multisite-user-model)

He basically create a field which combines the two field for USERNAME_FIELD. I'm not sure if there's a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the sites framework does not work with subdomains, as each site needs a unique SITE_ID in settings.py, so this is not an option for me I'm afraid.

Comment: umm? can't you just use client_id in place of his site_id?